# How to ignore lines with missing fields in the database

Tags: database, scala, bigdata, apache-spark

So I'm following the tutorial on [spark using scala](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/big-data-mini-course/data-exploration-using-spark.html), and working with [this dataset from wikimedia](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/2007/2007-12/pagecounts-20071209-180000.gz). I was interested in generating a histogram of total page views by language. The first column is language, while the third column is page views. However, it seems that some lines in that database do not have any field for the third column, as I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBondException` error when I run the following code.

```
scala> val tuples = pagecounts.map(line => line.split(" "))
scala> val keyValuePairs = tuples.map(line => (line(0).substring(0, 2), 
  line(2).toInt))
scala> keyValuePairs.reduceByKey(_+_, 1).collect
```

Does anyone have an idea, how to ignore the lines which have missing fields for the third column, so that I can run query against only those lines which contain the field for the third column in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to filter the page counts so that only the ones with 3 fields are being operated on. Use `filter` to select just those:

```
val tuples = pagecounts.map(line => line.split(" ").filter(_.length == 3))
```

Comment: Thanks Bob. But as it turned out, missing fields was not the problem. I have no idea why I still get out of bound error. Could it be due to file containing characters in chinese or japanese etc?

Comment: Without a stack trace or more context, it is difficult to say. Are you sure it is an array out of bounds error? You can get a "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range" error when your strings are the wrong length.